# Resign the keyboard when the user click in any area on the screen

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

The frame where the `UISearchBar` is drawn is the following:

```
UISearchBar *sBar=[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 40)];
```

Simply i want to dismiss the keyboard when the user click on **ANY** area than the area defined above.

Is there any `UISearchBar` delegate method to do so, or a simple way. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to handle click/touch events on the other views in your window, and call:

```
if (sBar.isFirstResponder)
    [sBar resignFirstResponder];
```

sBar will need to be a property of your UIViewController

To handle touch events, add these to your UIViewController:

```
  - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }

    - (void) touchesMoved:(NESet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }

    - (void) touchesEnded:(NESet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NESet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    }
```

and call [sBar resignFirstResponder] from at least the touchesBegan method.

Comment: Hi, what if i want to dismiss the keyboard when the user tap on ANY other area other than the search bar frame. I think it's easier than handling other views events.

Comment: right, but ultimately you're talking about a touch handler on your ViewController's main view, and handling TOUCH_DOWN events

Comment: I edited my question, so, is there any delegate method that can handle that?

Comment: edited answer to show touch handling.  Of course if you have UIButtons or other touch aware controls in your ViewController, then those handlers would also need to call resignFirstResponder.